# Turn on SOAP messages request/response logs

Tags: soap, service, weblogic

I am currently using weblogic and the stack produces this error when a SOAP request is sent to a web service:

Caused By: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Character reference "" is an invalid XML character.

at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:502)at com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.util.transform.EfficientStr

My question is, can I turn on some extra logging which will log the request and the response?

Answer (score 0):

To view the SOAP request and response messages, run your client application with the -Dweblogic.webservice.verbose=true flag,

```
java -Dweblogic.webservice.verbose=true my.app.RunService
```

The full SOAP request and response messages are printed in the command window from which you ran your client application.